# Find URL for NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802) error

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession, ios9

I'm getting the infamous `NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)` error on iOS 9.
I don't want to add a global exception but for specific domains.

How do I know which URL causes this error?

Answer (score 4):

When your NSURLConnection or NSURLSessionTask error handling delegate method is called, obtain the URL from the request object and print it with NSLog (or just put a debug breakpoint in that method).

Or set the CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS environment variable to 1 (or 2 or 3) if your code isn't making the request directly (e.g. if a third-party library is doing it on your behalf).

Comment: The easiest way to set the environment variable is to edit your debug build scheme and within that pane, edit the "Run" behavior to add a new environment variable, IIRC.  See here for screen shots: http://nshipster.com/launch-arguments-and-environment-variables/

Comment: You're sure that you're setting it in the build scheme that you're actually building?

Answer (score 4):

You can set CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS environment variable as @dgatwood suggested or you can call `setenv("CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS", "3", 1);`, for example, in main.m file. Once you have done any of options you should see appropriate message in console log:

> 2014-10-28 14:23:37.115 QTestbed[2626:60b] CFNetwork diagnostics log file created at: /private/var/mobile/Applications/76531F40-3291-4565-8C75-0438052C83BC/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/CFNetwork_com.example.apple-samplecode.QTestbed_2626.nwlrb.log

Just open this file after some time of usage of your app and check logs there.

Here is a [link to the related Apple's Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1887/_index.html).